# How to obtain a log file for Audit Window from JBoss Drools Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, drools

I'm using JBoss Drools 6.5.0 Final plugin in Eclipse Neon. When creating a new project, I choose the option of sample code generation. When I run example code from Drools 5.5.0 Final, it produces a file called `test.log` which I could then use in Audit window of Drools perspective. This was done in this part of the default code:

```
KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
```

This is not the case with 6.5.0 Final, because the example code does not contain the above line. When I tried to add it:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(kSession, "test");
```

I got a compilation error:

```
The method newFileLogger(KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager, String) in the type KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory is not applicable for the arguments (KieSession, String)
```

This is because new example code uses `KieSession` object and not `StatefulKnowledgeSession`. I tried casting the `kSession` to `StatefulKnowledgeSession`, but I get a cast exception.

What is the current way of obtaining `test.log` file?

Answer (score 1):

Please try out the following code:

```
KieRuntimeLogger kieLogger = ks.getLoggers().newFileLogger(kSession, "test");
```

And don't forget to close the `kieLogger` by using:

```
 kieLogger.close();
```

This code snippet will create a `test.log` file in your project folder. In case of using Eclipse Drools plugin you will be also able to use the so-called `Audit` view to visualize the content of log-file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast your ksession to KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager :

KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger((KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager) kSession, "test");